# How to prevent user from going back to form (all forms login, edit post, etc.) after submission in Django?

Tags: django

I'm new to django and I'm stuck with a problem. Please help me solve it.

**Problem:**
Whenever I fill a form, be it a login form, edit post form, create post form, etc., if I press browser's back button, it takes me back to it.

**What I want:**
Redirect the user to somewhere else rather than taking them back to form. Is there any way to perform it in django ? **I want to use CBVs only**

*"and yes, I don't wanna disable browser back button!"*

### Code:


**views.py**

```
class CreatePost(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin, CreateView):
model = Post
template_name = 'blog/create_post.html'
fields = ('category', 'title', 'meta_title', 'meta_description', 'content', 'image', 'image_alt_text')
user_check_failure_path = 'blog-home'

def test_func(self):
    return self.request.user.is_superuser

def handle_no_permission(self):
    if self.request.user.is_authenticated:
        messages.error(self.request, 'Permission Denied ! Only SUPERUSER can access this page', 'danger h4')
        return redirect('blog:blog-home')
    else:
        return redirect('accounts:login')



class Login(views.LoginView):
    template_name = 'accounts/login.html'
    redirect_authenticated_user = True
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this is possible for every URL. But for the login form, you can edit the url in auth/urls.py. you have to add "redirect_authenticated_user=True" inside the LoginView.as.view(<here>). This way you prevent already logged in users to visit the login page again

Answer (score 0):

In your settings.py file, set: `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'blog:blog-home'`
This will redirect a user to the blog-home URL whenever they successfully login.

In your CreatePost view, you should include a `success_url = 'blog:blog-home`
Or in some cases you can even use: `success_url = reverse_lazy('blog:blog-home')`
This will redirect the user to the specified URL upon successfully submitting a form.

Comment: This isn't what I want. I already did that. Problem is after redirecting, If I press broswer-back button, it takes me to that form again. I don't want that

Comment: Your question said "What I want: Redirect the user to somewhere else rather than taking them back to form" I think what you meant is going back to the page you were on prior to the form page. Like when you submit the form, you can click the back button to go back there. Is that what you want?

Comment: Yes boss...like if I was on blog home page and click create post and submit it, it gets redirected to blog home...Now, if i press browser-back button..it should take user to blog home page or any other page rather than create post page

Comment: I'm not sure you can alter the browser history stack to do that but you can always pass in a hidden input tag to capture the current URL that you can access in the view, like so:  `<input type="hidden" name="previous_page" value="{{ request.path }}">`.  You can then do: `    prev = request.POST.get('previous_page', '/')
                          return HttpResponseRedirect(prev)`